# MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback is not working - how to debug?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, webforms

I inherited some web shop project (`ASP.NET` 3.5, `Webforms`, `Visual Studio 2008 PRO`).
On one page I have `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` set to `true`.
When shopping cart (user control loaded in master page) is empty, then asp.net is not generating `Javascript` code required for scroll position. When I add some items to the cart, then everything works fine.

Can you give me any advice how to find part of the code which is responsible for this issue?
I don't have an access to the 3rd party profilers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you utilizing UpdatePanels in that specific page?

If Yes, following article may give you some direction:

http://basgun.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/maintain-scroll-position-updatepanel-postback/

If No, this one may assist:

[Javascript: Maintaining Page Scroll Position](http://web.archive.org/web/20130710044513/http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/156.aspx)
Here is the code from that article:

```
// function saves scroll position
function fScroll(val)
{
    var hidScroll = document.getElementById('hidScroll');
    hidScroll.value = val.scrollTop;
}

// function moves scroll position to saved value
function fScrollMove(what)
{
    var hidScroll = document.getElementById('hidScroll');
    document.getElementById(what).scrollTop = hidScroll.value;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="fScrollMove('div_scroll');" onunload="document.forms(0).submit()";>
<form>
<input type="text" id="hidScroll" name="a">< /br>
<div id="div_scroll" onscroll="fScroll(this);" 
style="overflow:auto;height:100px;width:100px;">

.. VERY LONG TEXT GOES HERE

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope one of these links help!