# Maintain scroll position of .aspx page in ASP.NET when maintainscrollpositiononpostback is set in web config and page directive

Tags: asp.net, scroll

I have asp.net page, inside form there are div's and server control. there are no update panels in my page. when ever i do postback (e.g button click, gridview selected index), scroll position is not maintained even though i have set Maintainscrollpositiononpostback in web config and page directive to true

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback ="true"  CodeFile="abc.aspx.vb" MasterPageFile="~/Index.master" Inherits="abc" %>
```

in web config

```
<pages enableSessionState="true" maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true">
  <namespaces>
    <clear/>
```

Comment: did you try to set the value in the page-directive in your .aspx?

Comment: @Homungus yes, i tried already but no success.

Comment: please show us, what you already tried - provide code/markup-samples.

Comment: @Homungus i have edited my question with code. Please preview it.

Comment: maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394852/how-to-maintain-page-scroll-position-after-a-page-postback-in-asp-net

Comment: @Homungus couldn't find any solution out of links